# How to get complete city data from Maps API's

Tags: json, google-maps, bing-maps

i needed little help on how to go about it. i do not have much knowledge about Google Maps  or Bing Maps API's as I am the database guy.

We are building an emergency response system of a city. So for this we are using Neo4J as the database which till now has been very satisfactory.

But now to generate the city map- Is there a way that I can get the details of the city ie basically all streets, landmarks etc etc in any format. Once I have this data, then i can imbed them in the database and proceed.

Basically a way to get the complete details of the city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Open Street Map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) and their [downloads page](http://planet.openstreetmap.org/) ([instructions and explanations](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data)). It will give all their data in XML format, which should exactly be what you need.

Comment: @Jatin - Oh really?  Are you willing to build an emergency response system that depends on maps for which you've got no quality assurance and no formal support?  What is the city ... so that I can avoid going there :-)